# android emulator could not open

Tags: android, android-emulator

when I open emulator the following screen displayed and continue to run but it is not open.[image]

This is the emulator for tablet.It is taking so much time to displayed.It is taking max 2 to 3 hours,but some time times it is not opened still running only.But when i open emulator for device it is open less time(3 t0 6 minutes).I searched alot in google i did'nt find any solution.And also i updated my android sdk.But there is no difference. Please suggest me what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It also depends on your system configuration, if your system config is low upgrade it or check in some other machine.

You can refer to this as well

[Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator?rq=1)